# Is there a way to view the size of my physics body with Swift?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocos2d-iphone, xcode6

I know that Cocos has something called debugDraw that outlines your physics bodies.  This is really helpful.  Is there something similar offered in Xcode or Swift?

Can't seem to find anything.  But I'd like to make sure my physics bodies are the proper sizes because they currently seem to be a bit bigger than they should be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was 1 more Google search short before I posted my question...Found the answer!

[How to draw SKNode PhysicsBody for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127221/how-to-draw-sknode-physicsbody-for-debugging)

Add this line "skView.showsPhysics = YES;" after "skView.showsFPS = YES;"

Comment: There are also methods for that in the SKUtils library: https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils